# FSM (Finite State Automaton and PDA (Push Down Automaton

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Say we have the following language, some number of a's and b's followed by three a's followed by some number of a's and b's

Show how you can create a finite state machine that will accept the words in the language and reject words, not in the language. Show the transition rules.

Show how you can create a PDA or push down automata that will accept the words in the language and reject words, not in the language. Show the transition rules.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you and future readers understand the concepts and algorithms but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really accomplish that. Please edit the question to show your partial progress. Above all, it is expected of you to raise **a thoughtful question**. Have you read [how to ask a good homework question](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284)?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the regular expression is `(a+b)*aaa(a+b)*`; one can now draw DFA/NFA based on this!
For the PDA one can do as follows: having a DFA/NFA write the same transition rules for PDA while having somy dummy stack operation (say pushing the symbol into the stack; and never pop it out) finally accept by final state in PDA (one can now empty the stack if required; and accept via empty stack)

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Nice answer, but please do not encourage undesirable posting behavior (by providing answers). See Apass.Jack's comment to the question.

Comment: Hello codeR thanks for the feedback I'm really struggling to understand these two concepts. So for the FSM we how am I showing how I can accept and reject words?

Comment: Also what would be transitions rules look like